# Vanishing reward function in Q-Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

Imagine that the agent receives a positive reward upon reaching a state $s$. Once the state $s$ has been reached the positive reward associated with it vanishes and appears somewhere else in the state space, say at state $s'$. The reward associated to $s'$ also vanishes when the agent visits that state once and re-appears at state $s$. This goes periodically forever. Will discounted Q-learning converge to the optimal policy in this setup? Is yes, is there any proof out there, I couldn't find anything.